# How to deactive a property for updating but not for creating in OpenXava?

Tags: java, user-interface, openxava

I have a property called date where the user should be able to enter value when creating a new entity:

[image: Date editable on creating new entity]

However, on editing an existing entity the date property should be not editable, in this way:

[image: Date not editable on editing an existing entity]

Is there an easy way to declare a property editable only on creating in an OpenXava entity?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just annotate your property with @ReadOnly(onCreate=false):

```
@ReadOnly(onCreate=false)
LocalDate date;
```

You don't need any extra code.